# Why isn't my updated data re-rendering?

Tags: d3.js

I'm playing around with the "update" pattern in D3.js.  I am just creating a simple bar graph that will update the data when you press the "Change" button.

My problem is that when you press the "Change" button, the first three rendered bars do not get re-rendered.  I debugged and saw that the data was properly applied (`__data__` was correct) but the re-application failed.

Here is my code and a link to it in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/GrEpk):

```
var myData = [ 100, 200, 300 ];

d3.select('body').append('button').text("Change").on("click", function() {
  myData = [200, 400, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];
  update(myData);
});

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("y", 30);

var update = function(data) {
  var bars = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(data);

  var groups = bars.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate(0," + i*25 + ")"});

  groups
    .append("rect")
    .attr("height", 25)
    .attr("fill", "pink")
    .attr("stroke", "white");

  groups
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 18)
    .attr("fill", "red");

  bars.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("width", String);

  bars.selectAll("text")
    .text(String);
}; 

update(myData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you change the `.selectAll()` in your update selection handling to `.select()`:

```
bars.select("rect")
  .attr("width", String);

bars.select("text")
  .text(String);
```

By using `selectAll()`, you're accessing the data that is bound to the elements that you're selecting (i.e. the rectangles and text elements), which was bound when you appended the elements. This data hasn't been updated though as you've only updated it for the containing `g` elements. Using `.select()` instead also binds the new data to the child elements.

The general pattern that you're using is a [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) and can be a bit confusing to start with and lead to unexpected results.